# How do you iterate through an arraylist , perform an operation in each object and store it back in the arraylist?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

How do you iterate through an arraylist , perform an operation in each object and store it back in the arraylist?

This process comes up pretty frequently and I have found a workable solution , but I would like to know what the best practice for addressing this situation is.

My general approach

- Iterate through each object of the ArrayList
- Get a copy of the object currently being pointed to
- Perform my operation on the copy.
- Overwrite the original item in the arraylist with the modified copy

It works, but I wonder if there is a more efficient or less error prone technique.

Thank you.

Comment: Well for anyone to provide a better solution you need to post some code. Telling us what you do won't help.

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot just modify the object in the ArrayList?  If you do an `SomeObject someObject = list.get(i);`, you can just call methods on someObject to modify it without having to make copies.  Clarification of the question may tell us why you can't do this...

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you don't need to do this.

- Get a copy of the object currently being pointed to
- Perform my operation on the copy.
- Overwrite the original item in the arraylist with the modified copy

You just need to get the original object and modify it. Then you
don't need to store it back to the array list, it is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is iterate through arraylist , access each object from list and the perofrm operation on that accessed object without copying to new object ,then automatically modified object gets updated in the list.

because when we get element from list , we actually get reference variable so if we modify using that , it will modify in the same memory location where your object resides.

for sample you can see below code i have executed on your  scenario

```
List<Fan> fans  = new ArrayList<Fan>();
        Fan f1 = new Fan();
        Fan f2 = new Fan();
        fans.add(f1);
        fans.add(f2);
        for (Fan fan : fans) {
            performOperation(fan);
        }

        for (Fan fan : fans) {
            System.out.println(fan.getName());
        }
    }

    private static void performOperation(Fan fan) {
        fan.setName("hai");

    }
```

performing operation on each Fan object and automatically its reflected and displayed in second for loop after modification

let me know for any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in an `ArrayList` are separate objects the list itself.

If you perform an operation on an object in the list, it's still in the list at the same position. You don't need to "overwrite" it.

```
class Name {
    String n;
    Name(String n) {this.n = n;}
    String getName() {return n;}
    void setName(String n) {this.n = n;}
}
...
List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add(new Name("Steve!"));
...
// shout louder
for (final Name name : names) {
    name.setName(name.getName().toUpperCase());
}
```

However, if the object is immutable (you can't change the contents of the object itself), you don't have the option to modify what's inside the object in the list. You need to overwrite the entry in the list with a new object. In that case, you need to keep track of where you are in the list:

```
class Name {
    final String n;
    Name(String n) {this.n = n;}
    String getName() {return n;}
}
...
List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add(new Name("Steve!"));
...
// shout louder
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    final Name name = names.get(i);
    names.put(i, new Name(name.getName().toUpperCase());
}
```